# SQL : How to find number of occurrences without using HAVING or COUNT?

Tags: sql

This is a trivial example, but I am trying to understand how to think creatively using SQL.

For example, I have the following tables below, and I want to query the names of `folks` who have three or more `questions`. How can I do this without using `HAVING` or `COUNT`? I wonder if this is possible using `JOINS` or something similar?

FOLKS

```
folkID      name
----------  --------------
01          Bill
02          Joe
03          Amy
04          Mike
05          Chris 
06          Elizabeth 
07          James 
08          Ashley
```

QUESTION

```
folkID      questionRating questionDate
----------  ----------     ----------
01          2              2011-01-22
01          4              2011-01-27
02          4
03          2              2011-01-20
03          4              2011-01-12
03          2              2011-01-30
04          3              2011-01-09
05          3              2011-01-27
05          2              2011-01-22
05          4
06          3              2011-01-15
06          5              2011-01-19
07          5              2011-01-20
08          3              2011-01-02
```

Comment: That's an interesting question. I don't really think Joins are going to matter much here though.

Comment: Can you use `CASE` and `SUM` to emulate `COUNT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SUM` or `CASE` seems to be cheating to me!

I'm not sure if it's possible in your current formulation, but if you add a primary key to the question table (`questionid`) then the following seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Folks.folkid, Folks.name
FROM ((Folks 
  INNER JOIN Question AS Question_1 ON Folks.folkid = Question_1.folkid) 
  INNER JOIN Question AS Question_2 ON Folks.folkid = Question_2.folkid) 
  INNER JOIN Question AS Question_3 ON Folks.folkid = Question_3.folkid
WHERE (((Question_1.questionid) <> [Question_2].[questionid] And 
        (Question_1.questionid) <> [Question_3].[questionid]) AND
        (Question_2.questionid) <> [Question_3].[questionid]);
```

Sorry, this is in MS Access SQL, but it should translate to any flavour of SQL.

Returns:

```
folkid  name
3       Amy
5       Chris
```

**Update:** Just to explain why this works. Each join will return all the question ids asked by that person. The where clauses then leaves only unique rows of question ids. If there are less than three questions asked then there will be no unique rows.

For example, Bill:

```
folkid  name  Question_3.questionid  Question_1.questionid  Question_2.questionid
1       Bill  1                      1                      1
1       Bill  1                      1                      2
1       Bill  1                      2                      1
1       Bill  1                      2                      2
1       Bill  2                      1                      1
1       Bill  2                      1                      2
1       Bill  2                      2                      1
1       Bill  2                      2                      2
```

There are no rows where all the ids are different.

however for Amy:

```
folkid  name  Question_3.questionid  Question_1.questionid  Question_2.questionid
3       Amy   4                      4                      5
3       Amy   4                      4                      4
3       Amy   4                      4                      6
3       Amy   4                      5                      4
3       Amy   4                      5                      5
3       Amy   4                      5                      6
3       Amy   4                      6                      4
3       Amy   4                      6                      5
3       Amy   4                      6                      6
3       Amy   5                      4                      4
3       Amy   5                      4                      5
3       Amy   5                      4                      6
3       Amy   5                      5                      4
3       Amy   5                      5                      5
3       Amy   5                      5                      6
3       Amy   5                      6                      4
3       Amy   5                      6                      5
3       Amy   5                      6                      6
3       Amy   6                      4                      4
3       Amy   6                      4                      5
3       Amy   6                      4                      6
3       Amy   6                      5                      4
3       Amy   6                      5                      5
3       Amy   6                      5                      6
3       Amy   6                      6                      4
3       Amy   6                      6                      5
3       Amy   6                      6                      6
```

There are several rows which have different ids and hence these get returned by the above query.

Comment: +1 @zelanix pretty intuitive....FYI, I used sum cuz the question didnt exclude the use of SUM :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try sum , to replace count.

```
  SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN Field_name >=3 THEN field_name  ELSE 0 END)
   FROM tabel_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT f.*
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY folkID) AS [Count] --count questions for folks
            ,a.folkID
        FROM QUESTION AS q
    ) AS p
    INNER JOIN FOLKS as f ON f.folkID = q.folkID
    WHERE p.[Count] > 3
```